# quick_xml::Reader, how to rewind buffer_position and read from start?

Tags: rust

I have an existing Rust project which uses quick_xml::Reader for parsing XML text, and I have discovered a few places where it loops over the file trying to find certain XML nodes, but it is sensitive to the order they appear since reading causes the internal buffer_position to increment.

Is there any way to rewind the reader to the start position and read from the beginning? I've been looking through the docs and source code, but couldn't find anything. Unfortunately Rust is not my strong language.

```rs
loop {
    match reader.read_event(&mut buf) {
        Ok(Event::Start(ref e)) => {
            if e.name() == self.name.as_bytes() {
                let result = reader.read_text(self.name.as_bytes(), &mut clone);
                if result.is_ok() {
                    return result.unwrap();
                }
                panic!("Cannot find {} value", self.name);
            }
        }
        Ok(Event::Eof) => {
            panic!("Cannot find {} value", self.name);
        } 
        Err(e) => panic!("Error at position {}: {:?}", reader.buffer_position(), e),
        _ => (),
    }
    buf.clear();
}
```

After this code is executed once on the reader and lets say it finds a node at the end of the XML, next calls will fail to find nodes that appear earlier in the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Reader` you supplied to `quick_xml::Reader::from_reader` needs to implement `Seek`. Then you can call `reader.get_mut().rewind()` which will reset the underlying `Reader`:

```
use quick_xml::events::Event;
use quick_xml::reader::Reader;
use std::io::{Cursor, Seek};

fn main() {
    // `Cursor` wraps a `AsRef<[u8]>` in a type that implements `Seek`
    // `File` also implements `Seek`
    let inner = Cursor::new(
        r#"
        <first>
            <second>Will never ever be read.</second>
        </first>
        "#,
    );

    let mut reader = Reader::from_reader(inner);
    reader.trim_text(true);

    let mut buf = Vec::new();

    for _ in 0..10 {
        match reader.read_event_into(&mut buf).unwrap() {
            Event::Start(e) => {
                println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(e.name().as_ref()));
                // after reading a `Start` event, rewind the underlying
                // buffer to the beginning
                reader.get_mut().rewind().unwrap();
            }
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}
```

This will print `first` ten times.