How to search an XML file starting at a specific position using quickxml?
I am trying to use the rust library quick_xml to find a child element of a parent (as a separate call from finding the parent itself). I can find a tag and get it's position. But I can't seem to load the file and jump to a position to start searching for a child element. I original thought I could just use SeekFrom::Start() but it seems to have no effect at all on the buffer position.
Can anyone help me with why the below code doesn't work?
let pos = tag.file_position as u64;
let mut xml_reader = Reader::from_file(&self.file_path).unwrap();
println!("Seeking to position: {} from {}", pos, xml_reader.buffer_position());
xml_reader.get_mut().seek(SeekFrom::Start(pos)).unwrap();
println!("Now at position: {}", xml_reader.buffer_position());

The test that executes the above section of code yields the following output
Seeking to position: 27031331 from 0
Now at position: 0

I had expected that reading the position after executing seek() would result in the position reporting 27031331 (the value of pos)

get_mut() "Gets a mutable reference to the underlying reader" so the following seek has no chance of informing quick_xml::Reader where you seek to. Since buffer_position has no constraints on R it cannot ask the underlying R where it is in the bytestream either, so it cannot respect it.

You cannot seek over XML while simultaneously parsing it. To know and recognize what's available and where in the document tree you are Reader has to observe every opening and closing tag up to your position.

Thanks! That is helpful. I came across this post of someone trying to do something similar, not sure why it works in that case (is it because it's a string?)  Especially when working with large documents, I would rather not store the entire XML tree in memory, seemed like caching the tag start positions of tags of interest would allow me to arbitrarily load the file and then query starting at the expected position. I came across this answer recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74357201/quick-xmlreader-how-to-rewind-buffer-position-and-read-from-start - do you know why it works?

Well it appears to work, but the quick_xml reader thinks it's reading 10 different first elements. You can see if you insert dbg!(reader.buffer_position()); in the loop. It'll print a different position everytime. You can get the same effect by copy&patsing the first element 10 times into the file read. In a similar way seeking the underlying reader is equivalent to truncating the beginning of the file.

Your first answer guided me in the right direction. Looks like the buffer_position of the quick_xml::Reader is not the same thing as the actual position in the file (stream_position).  If I actually look at the parsing results, the code above does start at the expected tag (obviously without any context regarding the layers above it). My println's were deceiving me into thinking it wasn't working as expected. Thanks for taking the time to help.
